# How to unit test code inside of ES6 Promise callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, es6-promise

Consider the following code:

```
import SomeOtherService from './some-other-service.js';

export new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
   const onSuccess=()=>{
      //More code
      resolve();
   };

   const onError=()=>{
      //More code
      reject();
   };

   SomeOtherService.asyncOperation(onSuccess,onError);
});
```

How do you test code inside the `Promise` callback?
The `Promise` must be kept from settling since that would mean the opposite is no longer testable. E.g. if it resolves, it can't reject and vice versa.

Would you mock Promise? If so, how? That's made difficult by it being used as the constructor.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the best way to test that, but what I can say is that you're cramming too much into that `Promise` constructor. The job of the `Promise` constructor is to convert the non-Promise API into a Promise one. Everything else should happen outside: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => SomeOtherService.asyncOperation(resolve, reject)).then(result => /* more code */).catch(err => /* more code */)` Once the result/error handling functions are moved outside, there is at least the possibility that you could export them and unit test them.